# Can't install libc++ on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, archlinux, libc++

I'm trying to install Discord which requires libc++.
AUR helpers just exit the installation and don't want to install this dependency.
If I do this manually I receive errors like this (via yaourt):

> ==> Downloading libc++ PKGBUILD from AUR... x .SRCINFO x PKGBUILD WoefulDerelict commented on 2018-07-21 11:28
>
> libc++ 6.0.1-1  (2018-07-11 23:09) ( Unsupported package: Potentially
>   dangerous ! )
>   ==> Edit PKGBUILD ? [Y/n] ("A" to abort)
>   ==> ------------------------------------
>   ==> n
>
> ==> ERROR: Running makepkg as root is not allowed as it can cause permanent, catastrophic damage to your system. Unable to read PKGBUILD

Also tried to install via pikaur:

> raise Exception(_(f"Can't copy '{from_path}' to '{to_path}'.")) Exception: Can't copy '/var/cache/pikaur/aur_repos/libc++' to
>   '/var/cache/pikaur/build/libc++/'.

Help me, please. Couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: The yaourt error is saying that you can't run yaourt as root. Instead of `sudo yaourt -S libc++`, run `yaourt -S libc++`

Answer (score 0):

that was a bug in systemd dynamic users isolation in `pikaur` (which is used when you running it as root) and it should be fixed by now